# Bent processor socket pins LGA1155 after overheating CPU

Tags: cpu, overheating, processor-socket

I have an i7-2600k (not overclocked) on an ASUS P8Z68 V-Pro motherboard that I was cooling using a Corsair H60 since last August. My A/C went out for a period of two weeks and my ambient temperature went up accordingly, of course, and at some stage the cooler quit. Luckily I was running ASUS AISuite and it notified me of high CPU temperatures, so I shut down the game I was playing to investigate.

Before I concluded the cooler had died, I did a little testing with the fan speeds and such, to try and determine where the issue might have originated, until finally thermal shutoff shut the machine down when the CPU reached 99C.

I changed the water cooler out for the stock cooler, after cleaning the CPU correctly with arctic silver cleaner and reapplying thermal paste; however, by accident I wiped the CPU dry with a non lint-free cloth and when I re-seated the CPU I noticed some had got into the socket pins. So I removed the CPU and using very fine tweezers I tried to remove the lint, but in the process bent some pins in the socket area. I then spent some time carefully bending them back into the original position, which didn't work for all of them but I felt I'd better leave them before they snap off from too much moving around. Anyway, cue a re-seat of the CPU and no boot whatsoever, and I got a little worried but didn't have time to delve into any repair as I had to leave town for a week.

Anyway, I'm now back and looking for advice on *what to do* and *where to start* before I go forking out 700 bucks on a new CPU and motherboard.

Thanks for any assistance!

Edit:
OK, so new motherboard installed and I used the old i2600k and it won't even boot. Everything spins up, but no POST beeps or anything, not even a flicker on the screen. Could I have fried my CPU as well?

Comment: "but in the process bent some pins in the socket area. Anyway, cue a re-seat of the CPU and no boot whatsoever" You skipped right over the part where you either spent some time carefully bending the pins back to how they should be, or just put the processor in the socket hoping that everything would seat right on it's own.  Which was it?

Comment: My apologies, I'll update in a second, but the answer is that I carefully spent some time bending them back in place. I do not believe any broke in the process.

Comment: It's Ok.  That was just an important detail.  What to do and where to start?  Break it all down again, triple check everything, and reassemble.  First thing to check are the pins on the processor.  If you didn't get them back just right, one or more could be bent or broken now.

Comment: OK. When I get home from the office I will do that. The major concern I have is that I know that not all the socket pins went back into place, but I was concerned that too much tinkering would break them. I don't remember if I checked the CPU pins, so will do that first. Thanks!

Comment: Unless you're intending on upgrading the CPU, I doubt a few bent pins  in the socket would necessitate replacing it, just the motherboard. It's never *good* to have a thermal shutdown, but the idea is to shut it down before it takes damage.

Comment: All it would take is one pin that didn't go into the hole it was supposed to.

Comment: Wouldn't POST, even after bending pins back into place; therefore, ordered a new mobo-better be safe than sorry and ruin the CPU too.

Comment: OK, so new motherboard installed and I used the old i2600k and it won't even boot. Everything spins up, but no POST beeps or anything, not even a flicker on the screen. Could I have fried my CPU as well?

Answer (score 0):

> and it won't even boot. Everything spins up, but no POST beeps or anything, not even a flicker on the screen. Could I have fried my CPU as well?

This sounds very similar to an issue I had with my desktop a few months back.

Try opening the cpu socket and checking inside it with a magnifying glass. It is very likely that a small piece of hair got down in there and is causing it to not respond. small paint brushes are great for removing stuff from sockets without damaging pins or leaving behind anything.

If that doesn't work...

- Try flashing your motherboard's BIOS
- Try the motherboard with just the CPU and no other components (Not even ram). (Should start beeping loudly). If not, you may have a dead processor :(
- Try pressing the ASUS "MEMOK" button

You may also be able to get your old MOBO repaired at a lower price!

Comment: The author specifically says they bent some pins which is a different issue then you describe but you don't really post an answer (solution) to the author's question  Most of your statements are comments.

Comment: In the edit, the OP said they got a new motherboard and it still will not start. Good point though, I edited my answer to be more of an answer!

Comment: Unfortnately this was quite some time ago, but thank you for your answer. I ended up ordering a new i7, to be safe. It is still purring along just fine. The new MoBo was also the v3, which allowed me to pull some extra performance out of it. As an aside, I have a barely used ASUS P8Z68 V-Pro for sale! :)

Comment: Glad to hear you got it all working, Paul!